# Common ApiController Base Class with Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, rest, swagger, webapi2

So i implemented my first REST API application and everything is working fine, including Swagger (I used Swashbuckle and can test my APIs)

In the documentation I read, "...Controller must extend from `ApiController`...". I get that. However, how literally should I take that statement? What I wanted to do is avoid replication of code in each of my `ApiController` extensions. For instance I have two controllers - `ProductController` and `DeviceController` - both of which extend `ApiController`. I created class `BaseController` extending `ApiController`. Then I changed base class for both Product Controller and Device Controller to Base Controller

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
}

public class ProductController : BaseController // ApiController
{
}

public class DeviceController : BaseController // ApiController
{
}
```

1) Swagger application has error as soon as I hit the /swagger URL. 
2) I really don't want my `BaseController` to even serve any requests. All I want is to have common helper methods I can use in all of my controllers such as `ProductController` and `DeviceController`.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Should just work. If you want help with the Swagger error, [edit] your question to include the Swagger error as well as your research.

Comment: Inheritance isn't the best way to reuse code. ASP.NET Core, MVC, Web API, all provide ways to add reusable functionality through filters.

Comment: Creating your own base class should work anyway. You should declare it `abstract` if you don't want it to be instantiated. Perhaps a better way though would be to create C# extension methods that can be called by any controller? Or put those common methods in "helper" or "utility" classes that can be used when needed?

Comment: okay I made my BaseController abstract and that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the @ApiIgnore annotation at the controller level.

```
   [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public class BaseController : ApiController
    {
    }
```

Comment: Easier to make the class abstract

Comment: of cource. There are different methods. yes easiser to make the class absract

Comment: yes like I said above, making the base abstract solved my swagger issue. However good to know about the @ApiIgnore attribute for future reference.

Comment: `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` hid all my classes that were inheriting from the base class. Making it `abstract` fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` also removes all inhering controllers.

I had to mark the methods in the base controller with the `[NonAction]` filter as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63845979/218408

Dotnet 5